# Shorten code and send to correct channel discord bot python

Tags: python, discord

I've been developing a discord bot for a small little something I plan on doing in the future, but it's not working the way I want it to be. is there a way to get the message to be sent to the channel I want it to be sent in?

Also, is there any way I could shorten my code? I'm really new to python so don't bully me for not knowing something obvious. here's the code:

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_any_role("Server Owner")
async def announce(ctx, days: int, hrs: int, mins: int):
  channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.author.guild.text_channels, name="announcements")
  if days == 0:
    if hrs == 0:
      if mins == 0:
        channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.author.guild.text_channels, name="new-channel")
        emb = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.green(), title="**Announcement Error**",description=f"A syntax error occured while trying to send announcement.")
        await channel.send(embed=emb)
        channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.author.guild.text_channels, name="announcements")
      elif mins >= 0:
        await ctx.channel.send(f"Overdrive will make an announcement in {mins} minutes! Make sure your online when it comes!")
      elif mins <= 0:
        channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.author.guild.text_channels, name="new-channel")
        emb = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.green(), title="**Announcement Error**",description=f"A syntax error occured while trying to send announcement.")
        await channel.send(embed=emb)
        channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.author.guild.text_channels, name="announcements")
      else:
        channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.author.guild.text_channels, name="new-channel")
        emb = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.green(), title="**Announcement Error**",description=f"A syntax error occured while trying to send announcement.")
        await channel.send(embed=emb)
        channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.author.guild.text_channels, name="announcements")
    elif hrs >= 0:
      if mins == 0:
        channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.author.guild.text_channels, name="announcements")
        await ctx.channel.send(f"Overdrive will make an announcement in {hrs} hours! Make sure your online when it comes!")
      elif mins >= 0:
        channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.author.guild.text_channels, name="announcements")
        await ctx.channel.send(f"Overdrive will make an announcement in {hrs} hours, and {mins} minutes! Make sure your online when it comes!")
      elif mins <= 0:
        channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.author.guild.text_channels, name="new-channel")
        emb = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.green(), title="**Announcement Error**",description=f"A syntax error occured while trying to send announcement.")
        await channel.send(embed=emb)
        channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.author.guild.text_channels, name="announcements")
      else:
        channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.author.guild.text_channels, name="new-channel")
        emb = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.green(), title="**Announcement Error**",description=f"A syntax error occured while trying to send announcement.")
        await channel.send(embed=emb)
    elif hrs <= 0:
      channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.author.guild.text_channels, name="new-channel")
      emb = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.green(), title="**Announcement Error**",description=f"A syntax error occured while trying to send announcement.")
      await channel.send(embed=emb)
      channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.author.guild.text_channels, name="announcements")
    else:
      channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.author.guild.text_channels, name="new-channel")
      emb = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.green(), title="**Announcement Error**",description=f"A syntax error occured while trying to send announcement.")
      await channel.send(embed=emb)
      channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.author.guild.text_channels, name="announcements")
  elif days >= 0:
    if hrs == 0:
      if mins == 0:
        channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.author.guild.text_channels, name="announcements")
        await ctx.channel.send(f"Overdrive will make an announcement in {days} days! Make sure your online when it comes!")
      elif mins >= 0:
        channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.author.guild.text_channels, name="announcements")
        await ctx.channel.send(f"Overdrive will make an announcement in {days} days, and {mins} minutes! Make sure your online when it comes!")
      elif mins <= 0:
        channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.author.guild.text_channels, name="new-channel")
        emb = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.green(), title="**Announcement Error**",description=f"A syntax error occured while trying to send announcement.")
        await channel.send(embed=emb)
        channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.author.guild.text_channels, name="announcements")
      else:
        channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.author.guild.text_channels, name="new-channel")
        emb = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.green(), title="**Announcement Error**",description=f"A syntax error occured while trying to send announcement.")
        await channel.send(embed=emb)
        channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.author.guild.text_channels, name="announcements")
    elif hrs >= 0:
      if mins == 0:
        channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.author.guild.text_channels, name="announcements")
        await ctx.channel.send(f"Overdrive will make an announcement in {days} days, and {hrs} hours! Make sure your online when it comes!")
      elif mins >= 0:
        channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.author.guild.text_channels, name="announcements")
        await ctx.channel.send(f"Overdrive will make an announcement in {days} days, {hrs} hours, and {mins} minutes! Make sure your online when it comes!")
      elif mins <= 0:
        channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.author.guild.text_channels, name="new-channel")
        emb = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.green(), title="**Announcement Error**",description=f"A syntax error occured while trying to send announcement.")
        await channel.send(embed=emb)
        channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.author.guild.text_channels, name="announcements")
      else:
        channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.author.guild.text_channels, name="new-channel")
        emb = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.green(), title="**Announcement Error**",description=f"A syntax error occured while trying to send announcement.")
        await channel.send(embed=emb)
        channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.author.guild.text_channels, name="announcements")
    elif hrs <= 0:
      channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.author.guild.text_channels, name="new-channel")
      emb = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.green(), title="**Announcement Error**",description=f"A syntax error occured while trying to send announcement.")
      await channel.send(embed=emb)
      channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.author.guild.text_channels, name="announcements")
    else:
      channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.author.guild.text_channels, name="new-channel")
      emb = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.green(), title="**Announcement Error**",description=f"A syntax error occured while trying to send announcement.")
      await channel.send(embed=emb)
      channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.author.guild.text_channels, name="announcements")
  elif days <= 0:
    channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.author.guild.text_channels, name="new-channel")
    emb = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.green(), title="**Announcement Error**",description=f"A syntax error occured while trying to send announcement.")
    await channel.send(embed=emb)
    channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.author.guild.text_channels, name="announcements")
  else:
    channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.author.guild.text_channels, name="new-channel")
    emb = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.green(), title="**Announcement Error**",description=f"A syntax error occured while trying to send announcement.")
    await channel.send(embed=emb)
    channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.author.guild.text_channels, name="announcements")
@announce.error
@commands.has_any_role("Server Owner")
async def announceError(ctx, error):
  if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.author.guild.text_channels, name="announcements")
    await ctx.channel.send(f"Overdrive is about to make an announcement! Make sure you're online when it comes!")
  else:
    channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.author.guild.text_channels, name="new-channel")
    emb = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.green(), title="**Announcement Error**",description=f"A syntax error occured while trying to send announcement.")
    await channel.send(embed=emb)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this does what you want in a more organized way.  My key mantra is DRY -- "don't repeat yourself".  BTW, if you have days == hrs == mins == 0, then shouldn't you be making the announcement?

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_any_role("Server Owner")
async def announce(ctx, days: int, hrs: int, mins: int):
  error = None
  description = None
  announcement = None

  if days < 0 or hrs < 0 or mins < 0:
    error="**Announcement Error**"
    description"A syntax error occured while trying to send announcement."
  elif days == 0 and hrs == 0 and mins == 0:
    announcement="Now is the time for the announcement"
  else:
    announcement = "Overdrive will make an annoucement in"
    if days:
      announcement += f" {days} days"
    if hrs:
      announcement += f" {hrs} hours"
    if mins:
      announcement += f" {mins} mins"
    announcement += "!  Make sure you're online when it comes!"

  if error:
    channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.author.guild.text_channels, name="new-channel")
    emb = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.green(), title=announcement,description=description)
    await channel.send(embed=emb)
  channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.author.guild.text_channels, name="announcements")
  if announcement:
    await ctx.channel.send(announcement)

@announce.error
@commands.has_any_role("Server Owner")
async def announceError(ctx, error):
  if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.author.guild.text_channels, name="announcements")
    await ctx.channel.send("Overdrive is about to make an announcement! Make sure you're online when it comes!")
  else:
    channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.author.guild.text_channels, name="new-channel")
    emb = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.green(), title="**Announcement Error**",description=f"A syntax error occured while trying to send announcement.")
    await channel.send(embed=emb)
```